# KrakenJS controller routing

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I have an admin controller `controllers/admin.js` that looks like this:

```
"use strict";

var AdminModel = require('../models/admin');


module.exports = function (router) {

    var model = new AdminModel();

    router.get('/admin', function (req, res) {

        res.send("Admin");

    });
};
```

If I start the application, getting the URL of http://localhost:8000/admin gives me `Cannot GET /admin`. However, getting /admin/admin gives me `Admin`.

My question is how do I get rid of the controller file name in the path of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first option is remove admin from router.get in admin.js controller

```
router.get('/admin', function (req, res) {
```

second check configuration in config director

config.json 
   
     `"router": {
               "module": {
                  "arguments": [{ "directory": "path:./controllers" }]
              }
          }`

edit :

third option create a folder admin in controllers folder copy index.js file from controllers folder result end url "/admin" (don't forget to change require location) and any other file in admin folder like "log.js" (path:"controllers/admin/log.js") create end url "/admin/log" by this method you an keep all admin code in different folder, this method helps managing large projects sometime to many folder also create mess ;)

router.get in admin/index.js or in log.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
```

using third method in my two projects for more study on controllers directory configuration : https://github.com/krakenjs/express-enrouten